# Vim macros don't work when using viper + vimpulse in Emacs

Tags: vim, emacs, viper-mode, vimpulse

Any other tweaks for making emacs as vim-like as possible would be appreciated as well.

Addendum: The main reason I don't just use vim is that I love how emacs lets you open a file in two different frames [ADDED: sorry, this was confusing: I mean separate *windows*, which emacs calls "frames"].  It's like making a vertical split but I don't have to have one enormous window.

Comment: Awesome - you're the first person to utilize bounty!

Comment: FYI, vim lets you open the same file in two different parts of the same vim instance.  You can also use vim tabs.  Not a solution, but an observation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could run VIM in [client server mode](http://www.vim.org/htmldoc/remote.html#clientserver), then you could have two windows connecting to one instance, hence removing the need for Emacs.

Comment: Dreeves: yes, this is exactly what pida IDE does, and it works fine.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how to make Vim macros work, but since you asked for tweaks for making emacs as vim-like as possible, here's a few additions to vimpulse I use everyday:

```
(define-key viper-vi-global-user-map [(delete)] 'delete-char)
(define-key viper-vi-global-user-map "/" 'isearch-forward-regexp)
(define-key viper-vi-global-user-map "?" 'isearch-backward-regexp)
(define-key viper-vi-global-user-map "\C-wh" 'windmove-left)
(define-key viper-vi-global-user-map "\C-wj" 'windmove-down)
(define-key viper-vi-global-user-map "\C-wk" 'windmove-up)
(define-key viper-vi-global-user-map "\C-wl" 'windmove-right)
(define-key viper-vi-global-user-map "\C-wv" '(lambda () (interactive)
                                                (split-window-horizontally)
                                                (other-window 1)
                                                (switch-to-buffer (other-buffer))))

(define-key viper-visual-mode-map "F" 'viper-find-char-backward)
(define-key viper-visual-mode-map "t" 'viper-goto-char-forward)
(define-key viper-visual-mode-map "T" 'viper-goto-char-backward)
(define-key viper-visual-mode-map "e" '(lambda ()
                                         (interactive)
                                         (viper-end-of-word 1)
                                         (viper-forward-char 1)))

(push '("only" (delete-other-windows)) ex-token-alist)
(push '("close" (delete-window)) ex-token-alist)
```

Of course, learning Emacs is very important too, but Emacs relies on customization to make it behave exactly like you want it to. And the default Vim key bindings are so comfortable that using Viper simply means that Viper does some Emacs customization for you.

As for using Vim instead of Emacs, I love Vim, but I love the interactiveness of the Lisp system that is Emacs. Nothing feels like typing a line of code anywhere in your editor and instantly evaluating it with a single keystroke, changing or inspecting the state of your editor *from your editor* (including the live documentation) with a single keystroke (`C-M-x`) *while it is running*.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have any viper or vimpulse tweaks for you, but I do recommend that you try follow-mode.

Of course I'd also recommend that you start learning Emacs too.  I mean, if you're in this far you might as well go through the tutorial and maybe have a look at emacswiki.

Answer (score 1):

The version of VIM I use support (Window version) support splitting a file into 2 different frames using "Ctrl+W s"...

Comment: Interesting; is this a windows-only feature?

Comment: 'CTRL+W s' is is the same as :split, there's still only one main Vim window. You can't individually minimize one of the windows or drag one of them onto a 2nd monitor.

Comment: I don't believe it's a Windows only feature. If I run the console version of vim I'm able to do the same.

@Peter: The question doesn't say anything about minimizing or dragging to additional monitors...

Comment: In my Windows version of gVim, "Ctrl-W s" (or "Ctrl-W v") splits in two windows, not two frames.

Answer (score 1):

Vim easily lets you open a file in two different frames:

`:split` to split it horizontally

`:vsplit` to split it vertically

You can split the screen as many times as you want between the same file, different files, or both.

`CTRL-w-w` switches frames.

`:resize +n` or `:resize -n` resizes the current frame.

Comment: Thanks, this is good, but it doesn't quite work for me.  For example, you can't put the frames on different monitors.

Comment: I must be missing something here, but if that's what you're trying to do, why not simply open the same file twice using two different vim windows?

Comment: Opening the file twice is not the same. You won't have a shared undo-history and if you edit both windows before saving, there's no way to merge. AFAIK Emacs doesn't do this ...

Comment: Peter is correct. In Emacs it works just like a split, despite being in different windows (what emacs calls "frames"). That's what I'm after.

Answer (score 1):

Emacs+vimpulse is awesome, but I think its right workflow is to liberally use emacs commands in combination to vim shortcuts. 
For example, emacs's macro shortcut F3 and F4 is easier than vim's qq and @q .
Also emacs commands are accessed through Alt+x, not : commands. Though vimpulse support a few important vim commands, they are there just for compatibility.

Followings are my vimpulse specific customizations.

.emacs

```
   ; I use C-d to quit emacs and vim
   (vimpulse-global-set-key 'vi-state (kbd "C-d") 'save-buffers-kill-terminal)
   ; use ; instead of :
   (vimpulse-global-set-key 'vi-state (kbd ";") 'viper-ex)
   ; use C-e instead of $. This works for all motion command too! (e.g. d C-e is easier to type than d$)
   (vimpulse-global-set-key 'vi-state (kbd "C-e") 'viper-goto-eol)
   (defun t_save() (interactive)(save-buffer)(viper-change-state-to-vi)) 
   (global-set-key (kbd "\C-s") 't_save) ; save using C-s instead of :w<CR> or C-x-s

    (defun command-line-diff (switch)
          (let ((file1 (pop command-line-args-left))
                (file2 (pop command-line-args-left)))
            (ediff file1 file2)))

    ;; Usage: emacs -diff file1 file2 (much better then vimdiff)
    (add-to-list 'command-switch-alist '("-diff" . command-line-diff))
```

If you like terminal, you can use emacs -nw. In this case, this clipboard add-on is useful. http://www.lingotrek.com/2010/12/integrating-emacs-with-x11-clipboard-in.html

.viper

```
    (setq viper-inhibit-startup-message 't)
    (setq viper-expert-level '3)
    (setq viper-ESC-key "\C-c") ; use C-c instead of ESC. unlike vim, C-c works perfectly with vimpulse.
```

Almost everything vim does can be as easily done (if not the same way) in emacs+vimpulse  but definitely not vice versa!

p.s. most of the suggestions above are supported by recent vimpulse BY DEFAULT.

Answer (score 0):

You could always start vim in a shell buffer and resize it so it filled the whole frame?

Answer (score 0):

If you want VIM functionality, it makes more sense to just install VIM!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I answer your question, as it is not entirely clear what you are asking (why the macro's are not working, or which tweaks are available for emulating vim in emacs)
so, is this your problem?:

> - One user who uses an ancient emacs-snapshot (from 2005) mentions
>     that this mode causes all the keys on
>     his keyboard to stop    working unless
>     he deletes the line that reads
>     'viper--key-maps    from the macro
>     my-get-emulation-keymap in this file

if it is, you can try the stated solution.

I got this information from [the emacs wiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/vimpulse.el), and it's a known bug.

Comment: In terms of the bounty, let's say the question is how to make vim macros work in viper/emacs.  Additional tips for closing the gap between true vim and vimpulse can be considered tie-breakers/bonus.