# What guide should I read to start learning Emacs?

Tags: emacs

I don't really know if this is a decent question or not, but I am fairly new to programming and looking for a good text editor to use. I have read [this question on Unix.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/986/34332) and [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1430164/1530429) which have convinced me that Emacs is the way to go. But I can't really find any good documentation that is aimed at people who have no idea what "M-x-foobar" means. Once again, this is probably too subjective for SO, but I thought I would try anyway.

Comment: I bought a book called "Learning GNU Emacs: A Guide to the World`s Most Extensible, Customizable Editor" which was reasonably helpful, if books are your thing.

Comment: @Noldorin, despite the fact emacs is main text editor, I've got some sympathy for your view, and I think if the OP is new to programming he ought to be careful about focussing on learning emacs. For me, emacs works well when you have a command line / scripting language, so I find it v helpful, e.g., for SQL, for R (via ESS), and for bash (and if you're on *nix it's good to know one editor which works well in ssh). However for programming proper languages Java C++ Python etc, in my view an IDE is far superior, so Eclipse, or Visual Studio or some language specific application. Just my tuppence.

Comment: @TooTone: Yeah, I can understand that point of view. For me, using vim (which is admittedly quite different to emacs, but of the same ilk) was just a no-go in programming workflow. I tried it for a couple of months but even when I was fairly quick at the commands, I found it involved too much thinking to edit. Plus I sorely missed all those IDE features, as you suggest.

Comment: I'd suggest you start with the menu entry "Help => Emacs Tutorial".

Answer (score 1):

According to my experience, Emacs is a huge topic to cover. I'd suggest you to start with its tutorial by selecting the first entry in the "Help" menu (or pressing <kbd>Ctrl+h</kbd>, then pressing <kbd>t</kbd>, which is denoted <kbd>C-h t</kbd> in Emacs style).

Then just follow your needs by reading specialized articles or documentation. A bunch of useful information you may find in an Emacs Info, which can be called by <kbd>C-h i</kbd> (<kbd>Ctrl+h</kbd>, then <kbd>i</kbd>).

Knowing at least a bit of Emacs Lisp would be very useful as it's used to configure the editor and sometimes helps understanding how some things work. For that you may find useful [An Introduction to Programming in Emacs Lisp](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/emacs-lisp-intro/html_node/index.html) (but you may find it in Emacs Info as well).

Answer (score 1):

If you're just starting programming, you've probably got enough on your plate without dealing with a crazy moon editor! [gedit](http://projects.gnome.org/gedit/) (Linux), [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) (Win) or [TextWrangler](http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/) (OS X) are all free and may be more familiar to you.

Still, Emacs is great if you're game. I learned from a couple of resources:

- O'Reilly's [Learning GNU Emacs](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596006488.do)
- Emacs' built-in tutorial - press <kbd>Ctrl-h</kbd> and then <kbd>t</kbd>.

These got me up-and-running quickly.

After you've learned the very basics, you'll want customize Emacs to make it more confortable. Download someone's Emacs configuration off GitHub and tweak that. The [Emacs Prelude](https://github.com/bbatsov/prelude) is very good.

From then on, it's all about building muscle-memory:

- Try to use Emacs for all the random mundane typing and editing you normally do
- Use the Emacs movement keys wherever you can, such as in your terminal program
- If you use OS X, most of the emacs movement keys work in text fields. Use those instead of the arrow keys to move around.

Emacs has a reputation for being hard on your hands - the key combos were designed for older keyboards from a more civilized age. If your pinky starts to hurt while you're learning, it's a good idea to remap your <kbd>Caps-Lock</kbd> key as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>.

Comment: I love when people downvote and don't give a reason!

Comment: it was a mistake, but I don't know how to undo it.  When I "click again to undo" it tells me "you last voted on this answer N min/hours ago, your vote is now locked in unless this answer is edited"

Comment: Heh, that's weird. Thanks for the explanation. :)