# VHDL tags not efficient in vim with ctags+taglist

Tags: vim, vhdl, ctags, taglist

I use Vim with ctags and Taglist plugins. When editing .vhd files, the tags are very poor (only the entity is displayed).

I don't know if ctags support for VHDL is weak or if Taglist is reading unefficiently the file created by ctags.

How can I fix that ? Is there another solution to create better tag for vhdl with ctags/taglist ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You might want to try Emacs, the VHDL mode is very advanced. http://www.iis.ee.ethz.ch/~zimmi/emacs/vhdl-mode.html

Comment: Err, I found emacs very difficult to learn. I couldn't make simple things works, as for opening new tabs among other things. So I dropped it (even if I tried VHDL mode). Also, there is too much shortcuts and the editor is not really good looking ... still, thanks for the info !

Comment: Recall the time when you migrated from GUI based editors to vim, was it difficult at the time? But once you got used to it, your productivity went up. Similarly Emacs maybe difficult initially, but once you get to know the way things work, it will become intuitive. You just need to find a good tutorial. You are the first person who is telling me that they don't want to use a great editor because of its looks. Do you know Emacs can be run inside the terminal too, separate ugly window is not necessary, maybe then it will look just like vim. And for VHDL you will never use any other editor.

Comment: Indeed, I recently migrated from GUI based editors to VIM. Now that my productivity is increasing, I'm really not willing to change again. What's in emacs that I won't have in vim (except present problem, which I'm sure has a solution somewhere) ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1430164/differences-between-emacs-and-vim

Comment: I was asking specificly for VHDL ...

Comment: See the link in my first comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you find ctags' support for something insufficient, you can extend it by adding a series of declarations to a .ctags file in your home directory. For example, for VHDL you could use the code found [here](http://0x7.ch/vim/vhdl/):

```
--langdef=vhdl
--langmap=vhdl:.vhd
--regex-vhdl=/^[ \t]*package[ \t]+([^ ]+) is/\1/d,package declarations/i
--regex-vhdl=/^[ \t]*package[ \t]+body[ \t]+([^ ]+) is/\1/b,package bodies/i
--regex-vhdl=/^[ \t]*architecture[ \t]+([^ ]+) of/\1/a,architecture specifications/i
--regex-vhdl=/^[ \t]*entity[ \t]+([^ ]+) is/\1/e,entities/i
--regex-vhdl=/^[ \t]*([^ \t:]+)[ \t]*:[ \t]*process[ \t]*\(/\1/p,processes/i
--regex-vhdl=/^[ \t]*function[ \t]+([a-z0-9_]+)/\1/f,functions/i
--regex-vhdl=/^[ \t]*procedure[ \t]+([a-z0-9_]+)/\1/r,procedures/i
--regex-vhdl=/^[ \t]*type[ \t]+([^ ]+) is/\1/t,type declarations/i
```

Comment: perfect, that did the trick ! Thanks, especially after 2 months.

Comment: No problem, I hate to see "use emacs" as an answer to vim questions.

Answer (score 3):

I've added 'variable', 'signal' and :(in|out) for port definitions based on the original .ctags file you suggested. I found that matching those also is more convenient

```
--langdef=vhdl
--langmap=vhdl:.vhd;.VHD
--regex-vhdl=/^[ \t]*signal[ \t]*([^ ]+)/\1/s,signals/i
--regex-vhdl=/^[ \t]*([^ ]+)[ \t]*:[ \t]*(in|out)/\1/p,ports/i
--regex-vhdl=/^[ \t]*variable[ \t]*([^ ]+)/\1/v,variable/i
--regex-vhdl=/^[ \t]*package[ \t]+([^ ]+) is/\1/d,package declarations/i
--regex-vhdl=/^[ \t]*package[ \t]+body[ \t]+([^ ]+) is/\1/b,package bodies/i        
--regex-vhdl=/^[ \t]*architecture[ \t]+([^ ]+) of/\1/a,architecture specifications/i
--regex-vhdl=/^[ \t]*entity[ \t]+([^ ]+) is/\1/e,entities/i                 
--regex-vhdl=/^[ \t]*([^ \t:]+)[ \t]*:[ \t]*process[ \t]*\(/\1/p,processes/i
--regex-vhdl=/^[ \t]*function[ \t]+([a-z0-9_]+)/\1/f,functions/i  
--regex-vhdl=/^[ \t]*procedure[ \t]+([a-z0-9_]+)/\1/r,procedures/i
--regex-vhdl=/^[ \t]*type[ \t]+([^ ]+) is/\1/t,type declarations/i
```

Answer (score 0):

Ctags is fundamentally broken, as it does not take into account scoping and overloading of names in VHDL. Just don't use it.

You can find more info *[in this blog post](http://www.sigasi.com/content/vhdl-emacs-mode-navigation-using-ctags-are-broken)*.

Comment: Is this your answer to my question: don't use it ? You could have tried to give something constructive instead of making your own blog promotion.